# IIS 7.5 - Windows Authetication FQDN

Tags: windows, php, iis, authentication, mediawiki

Currently, I have to implement an auto login function for my mediawiki and I have enabled windows authentication on my IIS 7.5. It is working on localhost without any prompt.

However, when I tried example.com/wiki/index.php it is giving me the prompt and after entering the credentials 3 times. I am given a 401.1 error. I've tried adding *.example.com to IE intranet zone but is not working.

My question is how to have the browsers (IE/Firefox/Chrome) to autologin for me when I use Fully Qualified Domain Name to access my site? Since it is working properly (no prompt) on localhost, I assume my settings are correct?

Another question is, how does the auto login works when deploy to live server since the client's browsers are not configured? I read something about group policy but I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Could anyone guide me to the correct direction? Thanks so much!!

Comment: This page has lots of helpful information and links https://sysadminspot.com/windows/google-chrome-and-ntlm-auto-logon-using-windows-authentication/

Comment: @user2320464 hi, thanks for your response! I managed to  solve by following the method 2 instructions here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

Now I have another question, when deployed to live server, since the client's browsers are not configured according to your link, is there a way that can be rolled out to all computers? Thanks. I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's answer: I managed to solve by following the method 2 instructions here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861 i.e. by setting the DisableLoopbackCheck registry key.